# Picking $2k$ sets from a $2^k$ collection under $2$ constraints

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, sorting

Assume we have a collection of $2^k$ different items and we need to pick $2k$ sets of different items out of it under the following constraints:

1. Each item must be picked at least in $2$ sets.
2. The intersection of at least $2$ different sets in which an item I appears contains only I itself, S<sub>i</sub> ∩ S<sub>j</sub> = I. The complementary sets of the picked sets should also obey this.

My approach is to line up the items in $k$ rows and run an initial pick of k sets with $2^k$ in each (the last one may be partial). Next i tried to formulate picking the other k sets by selecting extended diagonals from the above setting. While i believe this approach may be correct, i could not prove it for any value of $k$.

Help appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: As I read this, the sets $\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\}, \ldots, \{2k-1,2k\}, \{2k,1\}$ meet the conditions.

Comment: @alex.jordan this method fails in k>2, guess i was not clear enough but also the complementary sets need to obey the constraint. e.g. k=3 you have 8 items but entitled to just 6 sets where your pairs will be 12 23 34 45 56 67 leaving 78 present in all complementary sets (meaning you have to exploit triplets).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your sets as nodes $n_i=S_i$ of a complete graph and the intersections between sets as edges $e_{ij}=S_i\cap S_j$. Since you have $2k$ nodes, you will also have $k(2k-1)$ edges.

For each of the $2^k$ elements, you want to have a dedicated edge $e_{ij}=I$. If $k=1$ or $k>6$, $k(2k-1)<2^k$. Thus, it's not possible in general.

Comment: Thank you @Vasily Mitch, i assume that your last equation should read "If k=1 or k>6, k(2k−1) < 2^k", correct?
And, if i am allowing the number of sets/nodes to increase but remain O(k), do you think it enables a solution to the original question?

Comment: If the number of nodes is $O(k)$, the number of edges will be less than $O(k^2)<O(2^k)$